# onclick reset and showhide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got one button for reset and one link for hiding image. onclick is used for doing this. Now I need to use that 'hide' link to do both 'hide' and 'reset' on 'onclick'. The code is given below:

```html
<script>
    function myFrame6() {
        var ifr = document.getElementsByName('frame6')[0];
        ifr.src = ifr.src;
    }
</script>
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="myFrame2()" class="btn btn-primary">
    <a href="#" id="p6-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('p6');return false;">Hide image</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can either add the reset function call (I'm guessing that's myFrame2()) to the link's onclick separated by a semicolon like so:

```
onclick="showHide(); myFrame2()"
```

Or simply call `myFrame2();` and `showHide()` from the same function.

Answer (score 1):

Since you listed jquery in the tags I assume that you're using it hence I will provide a simple answer for it.

Jquery provides function called **toggle** which implements both **hide** and **show** functionality in it

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("img").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<button>Toggle between hiding and showing the image</button>

<img src="https://www.google.com.co/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to employ some sort of checking to toggle between two modes. I will not give you the exact answer as you did not ask an exact question.

You add the element on your event as an argument

```
onclick="toggleMe(this)"
```

Then on the function

```
function toggleMe(element){

  if (!element.istoggled ){
    //show element

    element.istoggled == true
  }

  if(element.istoggled ){
    //hide element

    element.istoggled == false;
  }

}
```

The *istoggled* attribute of the html element referenced by parameter *element* is user defined and defined via dot notation, you can use setAttribute and getAttribute if you want to be concise.